# How to detect http response code?

Tags: video.js

I use `video.js` player with HLS.
I would like to detect HTTP response code for each failed request, which `video.js` makes to play a video. For example, if a response is 304 then my code needs to make a special action (show a message).

`player.on('error', ...)` does not provide such information. As well as `tech` level error.

I need something like:
`player.on('request', function(response) { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I found is wrapping `video.xhr` object with special handler.

Example of the code (using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) library):

```
videojs.xhr = _.wrap(videojs.xhr, function(fn, options, callback) {

            var wrapped_callback = _.wrap(callback, function(cb_fn, error, response) {
                var args = _.rest(arguments, 1);
                console.log('Error', error);
                console.log('Response', response);
                var res = cb_fn.apply(this, args);
                return res;
            });

        return fn.apply(this, [options, wrapped_callback]);
        });
```